# How long can NAudio record sounds?

Tags: limit, naudio, recording

I'd like to record sounds from the speaker 80minutes. But,
NAudio seems to have a limit of recording time, about 30 minutes.
How can I change it longer?

Comment: You could restart the recording. Before the first one ends, start a second one and then have it take over. You might have to do a minor amount of byte comparison to figure out where to take over to have a smooth transition.

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice. I'll try it, but my poor programming may not complete it.